# Move beamer headline down

Tags: beamer, vspace, headline

I want to move the headline down, to make the text below the colourful stripes.
Now the headline looks like this:
[image: Headline]

\vspace does not help in the case of headline.
How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.